# Angular 5 checkbox checked status from data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

In my app data is coming from the server with nested arrays but there is no field for the check if the checkbox is checked or not so I added that field with foreach loop. This field has no effect even if it is true or false. My code is as follows.

```
this.testservice.getQuestions()
          .subscribe(
          resultArray => {
          this.questions = resultArray;
            this.questions.forEach(element => {
              element.Awnsers.forEach(elementA => {
                elementA.isChekced = true;
              });
            });
```

the html code for input is

```
<div *ngFor='let q of questions'>
<b>Question: </b>
  {{q.Question}}<br><br>
  <div *ngFor='let a of q.Awnsers'>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
             name="options"
             value="{{a.awnsers}}"
             (checked)="a.isChecked"
             (change)="testoption($event, a.Awnser)" />
             {{a.Awnser}}
  </label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Event the property isChecked is true for all the elements but they are not coming checked. Please help.

Comment: change ``(checked)='a.isChecked'`` to ``[checked]='a.isChecked'``

Comment: ``()`` in template is used for event binding and ``[]`` is used for data binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Angular version is 5 then I would use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[checked]` attribute, by using two-way data binding, you will get the current status of answer i.e `checked` or `unchecked`.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{a.awnsers}}" [(ngModel)]="a.isChecked" (change)="testoption(i, a.Awnser)" />
```

[A Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wun4uv)

Answer (score 2):

With angular it should be written as [checked] which indicates the data binding, change it as follows,

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{a.awnsers}}" [checked]="a.isChecked"  (change)="testoption($event, a.Awnser)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Beacause of animation, I used this way.

```
<input #checkInput type="checkbox" />

export class Component implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('checkInput', { static: false }) checkInput: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
  @Input() isOpen = false
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if(this.isOpen) {
      this.checkInput.nativeElement.click()
    }
  }
}
```